# Update Solr index by http request

Tags: curl, solr

Let's assume we have the following index structure:

```
    <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
    <field name="user" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

And we would like to add a single value to this index. In cookbook4 it's done by such command

***curl 'localhost:8983/solr/update?commit=true' -H 'Contenttype:
application/json' -d '[{"id":"1","user":{"add":"jack"}}]'***

How can I add value to index from java code by passing http request?

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to do this from Java code, you might consider looking at [SolrJ](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solrj) the Solr Java client. Alternately, if you just want to pass pure http requests and not use the SolrJ client, you can pass the http request body in multiple formats. Below are the links for sending in either XML or JSON

- [XML Messages for Updating a Solr Index](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateXmlMessages)
- [Updating a Solr Index with JSON](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateJSON)